# Regex to capture and store url

Tags: html, regex, perl, web-scraping

I'm very new to perl and I'm trying to harvest the links and images from a website. I'm currently reading about [regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and I've so far managed to get the lines of html that contain links or images (at least I believe so) with

```
/<img src|<a href/i     #I'm just comparing every line of html to this
```

But how do I capture and store the actual url? Basically to turn something like this:

```
<img src="http://i1.nyt.com/images/2014/03/23/us/23marriage2/23marriage2-largeHorizontal375.jpg"
```

Into this:

```
http://i1.nyt.com/images/2014/03/23/us/23marriage2/23marriage2-largeHorizontal375.jpg
```

Comment: You might consider parsing the data rather than treating it as a text string to match Regexes against.  There are a lot more permutations of HTML than any regex will ever be able to match.   http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-Parser-2.36/Parser.pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I recommend using something like e.g. [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) rather than regular expressions to parse HTML.

Saying that, you can of course try and use regexes to fetch what you're after - but it is very dependent on your source material. Something that generically would capture an img src or a href would be something a bit like (this assumes things such as double quotes always being used, for example, and will be much more brittle than a parsing solution):

```
/<img[^>]*?src="([^"]*)"|<a[^>]*?href="([^"]*)"/i
```

Then if it matches, an image URL would be in `$1`, or a link would be in `$2`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more modern web clients and parsers is [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) and [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo%3a%3aDOM).  There's an 8 minute webcast that does a pretty good job of introducing their capabilities: [`MojoCast episode 5`](http://mojocasts.com/e5)

In order to pull all of the links and images from your requested example, just the following would be necessary:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $dom = $ua->get('http://www.nytimes.com')->res->dom;

# Print all href's
for my $href ($dom->find('a')->attr('href')->each) {
    print "$href\n";
}

# Print all img src's
for my $img ($dom->find('img')->attr('src')->each) {
    print "$img\n";
}
```

Note: these modules are included in the base installation of [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicio.us/)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: `/(<img src|<a href)="([^"]*?)"/i` then you should use second capture group (second group of parentheses).

Comment: BTW this regexp doesn't try to capture a valid URL, it matches everything inside the "" (until next '"').

Comment: EDITED: I've forgot the * repeat to match 0 or more characters. Also added ? to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Also doesn't work if there's any other attributes between '<img|<a ' and ' src| href' respectively.

Comment: I know, that's why is quick and dirty ;)

Comment: you should also remove <img and <a because there may be some attributes before ;-)

Comment: @user1934618 I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I mean eg <a class="asdf" href=" ...
/(src|href)="([^"]*?)"/ig

Comment: I'm trying to check if it's working and either it's not or I'm going about this way wrong. I tried doing `push @array, /(<img src|<a href)="([^"]*?)"\i` then printing that array once I finished looping and all I get is a very small amount of html with no quotation marks.. The <a href stuff is still in there, just no quotes.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with the nytimes home page and when I tried printing that array all I got was like 10 links